# How to make multiple lazy columns scroll independently each other in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I want to make multiple LazyColumn scrolled simultaneously in Jetpack Compose.

But, It seems that one LazyColumn prevent other LazyColumn to be scrolled.

Below screenshots is my composable structure.

[image]

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MultipleLazyColumnScrollTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    MultipleLazyColumnInColumnTest()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MultipleLazyColumnInColumnTest() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(
                state = rememberScrollState(),
                flingBehavior = ScrollableDefaults.flingBehavior()
            )
    ) {
        MultiLazyColumnRow()

        val backgroundColorList = listOf(Color.Black, Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue)
        for (index in 0 until 10) {
            Spacer(
                Modifier
                    .background(color = backgroundColorList[index / 4])
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MultiLazyColumnRow() {
    Row(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            items(count = 100) {
                Text(
                    text = it.toString()
                )
            }
        }

        LazyColumn(
            Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            items(count = 100) {
                Text(text = it.toString())
            }
        }

        LazyColumn(
            Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            items(count = 100) {
                Text(text = it.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

As shown in gif image,

If Red one already is in scrolling state, Whenever I scroll green LazyColumn, green LazyColumn doesn't scrolled, and Scrollable Column is scrolled.

How can I achieve my specification?

Comment: Try to remove .verticalScroll(
                state = rememberScrollState(),
                flingBehavior = ScrollableDefaults.flingBehavior()
            ) for Column

Comment: Removing .verticalScroll( state = rememberScrollState(), flingBehavior = ScrollableDefaults.flingBehavior() ) fix the issue. But I also want for Column to scroll, too.

Comment: You can try to use .nestedScroll()